# Is there a way of specifing a wildcard route in Ktor?

Tags: api, http, kotlin, ktor

I would like to have the same handler for all OPTIONS requests in KTOR. I'm looking for something of the type:

```kotlin
install(Routing) {

    route("**", HttpMethod.Options) {
        handler()
    }
}
```

Can you actually do this? Please provide an example if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle all `OPTIONS` requests you can use tailcard route pattern:

```
routing {
    options("{...}") {
        call.respondText { "Any options" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup. Is that simple. +1 and accepted Thanks! But if you have another handler for a specific options route it crashes. Any idea how to stop propagating the "endpoint check"?

Comment: You can just put more specific routes before one with a tailcard.